# Best Scala practice to map Option of Collection of specific type

Tags: scala

Specific case that I have encountered. How to handle effectively Scala Option of Collections of specific type?

As mentioned in one of the answers, using `Option` of Collection is not optimal and it's better to represent the absence of values with empty collection. But, this signature is force of me  by a wacky external service.

So, and example. I have:

```
val myData = Option[Seq[MyObj]]

case class MyObj(name: String)
```

I want to map `myData` to some other type which is an Seq of `NewObj`.

```
val newData: Seq[NewObj] = myData.XXX
```

What is the best practice to map `myData` to different object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `Option[Seq[Obj]]` is given, I'd `getOrElse` the option with an empty sequeunce:

```
object NewTest {
  case class MyObj(name: String)
  case class OtherObj(name: String, hash: Int)

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val myData: Option[Seq[MyObj]] = Some(Seq(MyObj("a")))
    val transformed: Seq[OtherObj] = 
      myData
        .getOrElse(Seq.empty[MyObj])
        .map(obj => OtherObj(obj.name, obj.name.hashCode))
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I would first say that you should rethink the need for an `Option` of a collection. It is typically preferred to simply represent the absence of values with an empty collection.

But if you really need the `Option`, then you can do this assuming `transform` is of type `(MyObj) => MyNewObj`:

```
val nyNewData: Option[Seq[MyNewObj]] = myData.map(_.map(transform))
```

Comment: I totally agree with you. But, Option of a collection is forced on me :) [wacky external service]

Answer (score 0):

```
myData.map(list => list.map(myObj => doThing(myObj)))
// Option[Seq[NewThing]]
```